# Problem watching youtube or other videos fullscreen in TWebbrowser under Android using delphi

Tags: android, delphi, video, youtube, twebbrowser

I'm doing an App for android using delphi FMX and TWebbrowser, the user would select a video from the listview which will then playback the video in a TWebbrowser control, the problem I'm facing is, even if the video is a youtube video as an example, I press on the maximize symbol, the video wont go fullscreen, nothing changes. is the a work around or am I doing something wrong. thanks. I'm using delphi 10.3.3

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything wrong - TWebBrowser needs to use a descendant of WebChromeClient (something that must be done in Java) that implements certain methods, as per this article:

https://medium.com/@oliverdamjan2013/fullscreen-youtube-video-in-webview-android-21f1c778cf56

I do something similar in this demo:

https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Kastri/tree/master/Demos/WebBrowserFileChooser

Which makes use of a descendant of WebChromeClient that implements onShowFileChooser. The folder that has the Java code is here:

https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Kastri/tree/master/Java/WebChromeClient

The code could be extended to implement the necessary methods (onShowCustomView etc) as per the other article linked to.

**EDIT 10-NOV-2020**

I've now updated the underlying Java code and updated the demo here:

https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Kastri/tree/master/Demos/WebBrowserFileChooser

(rather than create a whole new demo)

To support viewing YouTube videos full screen. **Please note that the demo relies on files in the Kastri library**

Comment: Thanks again for your help, but i tried the last 3 days trying to understand the work you've done, complicated i can say. using Java in delphi is for me new and I have no idea in implementing the new function into it. would it be to much to ask if you could help in implementing it?. thanks again

Comment: Please email me about it. myEmail := 'david' + 'n' + '@radsoft.com' + '.au';

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm so sad that I just noticed your updates. again great job thanks again for your greaaat support. Best regards